# Defining struct in Swift Mac App

Tags: swift, macos, swift3

I am defining a structure in a Mac App using Swift

```
struct ConfigData {
    var AddressType : UInt8
    var AddressX : UInt32
    var AddressY : UInt32
    var AddressZ : UInt32
}
```

The struct size is returned as 16 (which is incorrect) but when I change 
the order of the structure to

```
struct ConfigData {
    var AddressX : UInt32
    var AddressY : UInt32
    var AddressZ : UInt32
    var AddressType : UInt8
}
```

The count is printed correctly as 13. Is there anything I am doing incorrectly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a result of the need to keep the variables aligned at 4-byte boundaries. In your first example, three bytes of padding are going to be added so that the addresses of AddressX, AddressY, and AddressZ are properly aligned. In your second example, everything is aligned at a 4-byte boundary already, so no padding is needed.

Answer (score 2):

The size 16 is not incorrect because Swift makes no guarantees about the layout and alignment of fields in a native Swift struct. Presumably, in the current version of Swift, it is padding the `UInt8` field to 4 bytes so the following `UInt32` fields are 4-byte aligned for performance.

There is no guarantee that future versions of Swift will lay out the structure the same way, [at least until the Swift ABI is finalized](https://swift.org/abi-stability/). There are several relevant issues open in the Swift bug tracker:

- [Determine if the layout algorithm for structs should layout fields in a different order than declared](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3723)
- [Evaluate a fully declaration-order-agnostic layout algorithm for structs](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3724)
- [Determine if struct data members are addressable or bit-packed](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3725)
- [Decide the cap of alignment for struct layout](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-3912)

Also note that if you want an array of `ConfigData`, you should use `MemoryLayout<ConfigData>.stride` to measure the size, because Swift may include padding between array elements (again, for performance). You'll probably find that both layouts of `ConfigData` have a stride of 16.

If you care about the byte layout of your struct, you need to define it in C, probably using [compiler extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.3/gcc/Type-Attributes.html) to precisely control where the compiler inserts (or doesn't insert) padding.

Answer (score 2):

***Is there anything I am doing incorrectly***

NO, nothing wrong. You just need to know *alignment*.

Swift compiler aligns `UInt32` members to 4-byte boundary, and, as you know, `UInt8` takes just one byte. So, your first `ConfigData` is represented in memory(*) as:

```
AddressType | |x|x|x|
AddressX    |       |
AddressY    |       |
AddressZ    |       |
```

where `x` means padding byte to align following members.

And in your second `ConfigData`, internal representation would be:

```
AddressX    |       |
AddressY    |       |
AddressZ    |       |
AddressType | |
```

In the latter case, `MemoryLayout<ConfigData>.size` does not count trailing unaligned bytes. As some byte variable can be allocated there.

But if you allocate multiple `ConfigData` in an array, Swift adds padding bytes at the bottom. So, **`MemoryLayout<ConfigData>.stride`** returns the count for this purpose which is `16` for both `ConfigData`.

(*) Swift does not guarantee the member allocation of structs. And the details may change in the future till ABI stability will be stated.

---

Seems I am late and my answer is just illustrating some part of rob mayoff's answer. Please read it carefully.